# Imageview in framelayout not visible

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

Hi I am developing an android video app. I have a button in frame layout as in below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camerabutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/videocamera"
        android:text="REC"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how, I am using the `FrameLayout onCreate`

```
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
    final FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);
```

where getCameraInstance is as below

```
private Camera getCameraInstance()
{
    try 
    {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

and the `MyCameraSurfaceView` is as below-

```
public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView 
                                    implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera)
    {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
            int height)
    {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        try 
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        // start preview with new settings
        try 
        {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

The button in the frame layout is `not visible`. I have very less knowledge on frame layout. I am not sure how to make the button visible. 
Please 
 help. Thanks!

Comment: everything looks fine, what is the exact problem? what are you expecting?

Comment: `android:src="@drawable/videocamera"` in place of this try `android:background="@drawable/videocamera"`

Comment: @AhmedEkri I have update my question with the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove text and textSize from ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/camerabutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/videocamera" />
```

if problem persists, please post the screenshot.

Comment: I have edited my question. what changes do i need to make in it. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you wantimage and text both in view than use button

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camerabutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="REC"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have changed as above. Still the same problem exsists. I have edited my question. what changes do i need to make in it. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

try this we want rightside use this `android:layout_gravity="right"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

 <FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/videoview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/camerabutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_check"
    android:text="REC"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
  </FrameLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just add there lines before adding Preview to Frame View**

FrameLayout.LayoutParams previewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

myCameraPreview.addView(mPreview, 0, previewLayoutParams);